# I want to display model popup in listview in that model popup i want to display each row data in that model popup

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

i am trying to get the model popup on the click of a row but I dont know how to handle and display a model popup and how to identify the row id to get the data of that perticular row from the database.
go please try give me suggestion to display modelpopup .

below in that bootstrap modelbox in the place of lable text i want to display the details of that row data

### this is my .aspx file :

```
<!-- listview starting   -->
          <asp:ListView runat="server"  ID="listview1" ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder4"  >
                                          <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                              <p class="control-label">OOPS! No Data Available</p>

                                           </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                           <LayoutTemplate>
                                              <table id="myTable2" class="table table-striped">  
                                             <thead>  
                                                <tr>  
                                                <th>SNo.</th>  
                                                <th>Date</th>  
                                                <th>Subject</th>  
                                                <th>Content</th>
                                                <th>Acknowledgement</th>
                                          </tr>  
                                            </thead>  
                                            <tbody>  
                                             <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder4" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                                </tbody>
                                                   </table>
                                           </LayoutTemplate>

                                           <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <tr>  
                                                <td>1</td> 
                                                <td><%# Eval("noti_date") %></td> 
                                                <td><%# Eval("noti_subject") %></td> 
                                                <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" data-toggle="modal" runat="server" data-target="#notifyModal" style="cursor:pointer;" Text='<%# Eval("noti_content") %>' ></asp:LinkButton></td>
                                                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check green "><%# Eval("ack") %></span></td>   

                                                </tr>  

                                          </ItemTemplate>          
                                 </asp:ListView>
<!-- listview end -->
<!-- model popup start -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="notifyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                              <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Notifications</h4>
                                                  </div>
                                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                                      <table class="table">
                                                          <tbody >
                                                              <tr>
                                                                  <td  style="border-top:none"></td><td  style="border-top:none"><b><asp:Label ID="lbl_date" CssClass="red" runat="server" Text="22/5/2015"></asp:Label></b></td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                              <tr>
                                                                   <td  style="border-top:none">Subject</td> <td  style="border-top:none"><asp:Label ID="lbl_sub" runat="server" Text="Update the Status"></asp:Label></td> 
                                                               </tr>
                                                              <tr>
                                                               <td  style="border-top:none">Sent By</td>  <td  style="border-top:none"><asp:Label ID="lbl_sentby" runat="server" Text="info@amcsquare.com"></asp:Label></td>
                                                              </tr> 
                                                              <tr>
                                                                  <td colspan="2"  style="border-top:none"><div class="panel panel-default" style="width:100%;"><div class="panel-body"><asp:Label ID="lbl_content" runat="server" Text="This is to inform you about Update your Status..."></asp:Label></div></div></td>
                                                              </tr>

                                                               <tr>
                                                                  <td  style="border-top:none"></td>  <td  style="border-top:none"> <div style="text-align:right;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Acknowledge</button></div></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                          </table>
                                                  </div>

                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                       </div>
 <!-- model popup end    -->
```

### code behind file is :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            userid = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                listview1.DataSource = UpdateProfile.getnotifications(userid);
                listview1.DataBind();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Default2.aspx");
        }
    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: How you have tried show data in `Modal popup`? Change question - `Model` to `Modal`

Answer (score 0):

for modal pop-up you can use the following code

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

```
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1"   TargetControlID="Id of your Button On which you want to show popup"
CancelControlID="btnClose">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center"  Height="153px" Width="152px" >
<strong>This is an ASP.Net AJAX ModalPopupExtender Example</strong><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
</asp:Panel>
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
```

CSS Class

```
<style type="text/css">
.modalBackground
{
    background-color: Black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.modalPopup
{
    border: 3px solid black;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
    }
```